# Alternatives au mot "Travesti" ?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, synonymes, genre-biologique

Quels sont les mots ou expressions les plus appropriées pour désigner une personne de sexe biologique masculin portant des vêtements traditionnellement féminins (les déguisements grossiers ne comptent pas) ?
Je cherche un mot ou une expression synonyme pour décrire la personne uniquement du point de vue de son apparence (corps masculin + vêtements féminins).

Ou pour le dire autrement, existe-t-il un mot pour désigner un "travesti" lorsque on ne sais pas si la personne en question est transgenre ou non?

Comment: Bon. J'arrive pas à mieux formuler cette question. N'hésitez pas à me le dire s'il y a des choses à éditer pour la rendre plus claire ou plus respectueuse.

Comment: J'ai du mal à comprendre le deuxième paragraphe. Si tu penses que la personne est transgenre (et transexuelle ? tu fais une différence dans le cas présent ?), qu'elle s'identifie comme femme, et porte des vêtements féminins, alors le plus respectueux est peut-être de l'appeller "une femme" (+ "trans" si tu veux mettre l'accent dessus).

Comment: Si on cherche des synonymes de "travesti", on ne trouve rien : http://www.synonymo.fr/synonyme/travesti

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Je voulais savoir s'il y a un mot neutre qui puisse être utilisé dans le cas où on ne sais vraiment pas si c'est un homme travesti ou une femme transgenre, sans que ça soit irrespectueux s'il s'avère que la personne en question est trans. Mais apparemment il n'y en a pas, donc je vais sûrement utiliser périphrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu penses que c'est simplement un homme qui porte des vêtements féminins, alors je suggère "**un homme qui porte des vêtements féminins**", et éventuellement "**androgyne**" si ça ressemble à ça.

Si tu penses que c'est une personne trans qui a été un homme et qui est maintenant une femme, je suggère... "**une femme** (trans)".

Answer (score 0):

« Travesti » me semble être le mot le plus approprié. Il souligne bien le côté **vesti**mentaire du phénomène.

Les autres mots qui me viennent à l’esprit : folle, tante, tapette, etc… s’applique à l’homosexualité de manière générale, donc pas spécialement au fait de s’habiller avec des vêtements destinés au sexe opposé.

Comment: En effet il me semble que techniquement c'est le mot qui souligne le plus ce côté là. Par contre je cherchais un mot qui soit vraiment neutre, pas injurieux comme folle, tante et tapette... Au pire, une périphrase suffira.